# How to parse a json with date exported by mongoexport in Scala?

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

Given this code example:

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
val json = """{"date" : { "$date" : 1327064009959 }}"""
val doc = JSON.parse(json)
```

I get this error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

What can I do to get this parsed correctly in Scala with Casbah?

Comment: check your json and validate in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The json IS valid. It is the $date which causes problems while parsing in scala

Comment: Just enclose the seconds in double quotes. `"""{"date" : { "$date" : "1327064009959" }}"""` and file a bug against Casbah that it doesn't support longs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, which I don't like too much, thou:

```
import com.mongodb.util.JSON
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val json = """{"date" : { "$date" : 1327064009959 }}"""
val doc = JSON.parse(json)
var regex = new Regex("""\{ "\$date" : (\d+) \}""", "date")
val fixed = regex replaceAllIn (json, m => "\"" + (new DateTime(m.group("date").toLong)) + "\"" )
val doc = JSON.parse(fixed).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Check this typo, this is the valid JSON you should pass**

```
var json = '
    {
        "date": {
            "$date": 1327064009959
        }
    }';
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not messing up javascript with scala? Cause I sure it wont even compile in scala, cause ticks are used by characters, not strings: `val ok = 'x'` and this will throw an error: `val notOk = 'notOk'`. Hence your solution is meaningless.